# How to create and add asp.net page programmatically to Asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I am working on a project CMS where i am creating pages dynamically using html editor .My achievement is that i have created html page successfully now problem is that i am stuck to the point how to create asp.net page using c# and assigning it to master page 2 major problems.

1-the page created in directory that is current and not open on local host or domain that shows that it is not a part of project.

2-How to create asp.net page using master page programaticaly so that in its body tag i  will add the created html page located in current directory.

so tell me how should i create asp.net page and make it the part of project too and assign it a master page here is a code how i am creating html page in current directory

```
        string content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><header><title>{MY_TITLE}</title></header><body>{body}</body></html>";

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        content = content.Replace("{MY_TITLE}", titleTextBox.Text);
        string name = TextBox1.Text;
        content = content.Replace("{body}", Editor2.Content);
        lines.Add(content);
        string nameP = seelctName(Convert.ToInt32(name));
        nameP = nameP.Replace(" ", "");
        File.WriteAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + nameP + ".htm", lines.ToArray());
```

But i am thinking to assign this inner content to newly created asp.net page using c# linked to master page and make it a part of project mean open in domain too

Comment: If I understand what you need, have you tried to do it with templates and T4? Is the default template engine of VS. It lets you "program" pages, controllers and anything test-based creation. I use it to automate language and look&feel setings, even grid creation (I automated Telerik's Kendo Grid index page creation). Just do Right click-new.
Give this a chance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Comment: BUT THERE IS NO TUTURIAL FOR THAT HOW BEGINEER START AND MAKE HTML OR ASP.NET PAGES USING THAT TEMPLATE

Comment: I am going to add an answer with some details, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T4 is like old asp pages. Think on a script like php or asp on visual basic with all those <% %> things. They create an "output". Than output can be anyhing. However, they have access to your project, so they can make use of some info on your classes. So I asume you already have some experience on doing so, on any scripting language.

You should really follow the tutorials at :

**[ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx ]**

Ok, let's go.

When you create a new project, you have a a model, a view and a controller's directory (plus others). 
First create a little class inside Model:

```
public class CarsModel
{
  public string Brand {get;set;}
  public string Model {get;set;}
  [Display(Name="Kilometers per hour")]
  public double Speed {get;Set;}
}
```

Enter there and open HomeController. Add a new method:

```
public ActionResult MyList()
{
  List<CarsModel> myList = new List<CarsModel>();

  myList.Add( new CarsModel() { Brand = "Ford", Model = "F50", Speed = 150} );
  myList.Add( new CarsModel() { Brand = "Lamborgini", Model = "Countach", Speed = 290} );
  myList.Add( new CarsModel() { Brand = "Mattel", Model = "RedShadow", Speed = 5} );

  return View(myList);
}
```

Now, compile. Right-Click on MyList() and select "Add View" (Usually first or second option on context menu). Fill it as shown (mine is in spanish, but be sure to clear database context)

[image]

Click Ok. T4 will create a view for you. Great, right?

Let's see how it works.

On your project, create a [ CodeTemplates ] folder on your web project's root.
Inside create another folder, [ MvcView ]. You should end with [ CodeTemplates\MvcView ].

Now we will copy Microsoft's default templates so you can play with them.

Open [ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView" ] in Explorer. You shouls see a list of files:

[image: Default t4 directory]
Copy those files into your project, in the folder we just created  ([CodeTemplates\MvcView])

You can automate code creation, html, cshtml, txt... anything you want. I will show now how "List" works.

Open "List.cs.t4" inside your project. If you modify anything wrong, you can copy over the original file.

Everything between <# #> is code and will be executed or evaluated.

Let's check some lines. Line numbers may vary a little.

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>
<#@ include file="Imports.include.t4" #>
@model IEnumerable<#= "<" + ViewDataTypeName + ">" #>
```

First one: We will use c# for scriptoing (no vb)
Second one: Extension. It's clear, right?
Third one: There are some routins I will use: Include them (Imports.include.t4 in same directory)
Fourth one: It writes the following into the file:

```
@Model IEnumerable **SomeGgeneratedCode**
```

**SomegeneratedCode** is **<#=** "<" **+ ViewDataTypeName +** ">" **#>**. Says:
Write "<" + the name of my view type (CarsModel) + ">", or [< CarsModel >]
So, it writes

```
@Model IEnumerable<CarsModel>
```

So, it's your MVC model for your view. Nice, right?

Now, let's move ahead.

```
<#
// The following chained if-statement outputs the file header code and markup for a partial view, a view using a layout page, or a regular view.
if(IsPartialView) {
#>

<#
} else if(IsLayoutPageSelected) {
#>
// Generated code for a page with a layout (which is taken from the "Add View" dialog)
```

Around line 40 you have

```
<title><#= ViewName #></title>
```

The [<#= ] is like classic ASP. It menas "write result here", ie, the ViewName variable, which is taken from the dialog also.

Line 48:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

You can change some stuff, like me. For example,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Nuevo", "Create", { id = ViewBag.parentId }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs" })
```

That will create a different link, in spanish, with bootstrap css for a button and an id for a route parameter, in case this is a child view :). No t4 in this group, but just hard code personalisation!

Next lines, 53-56, you can guess what is doing. It searches for a "primary key". Our model don't have it, so will be skipped.

Line 74: is writing < TD > < /TD > inside a table.

I will "indent" it for you.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
    <#
    foreach (PropertyMetadata property in properties) {
        if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsPrimaryKey && !property.IsForeignKey) {
    #>
        <#
                // We do not want to show any association properties for which there is
                // no associated foreign key.
                if (property.IsAssociation && GetRelatedModelMetadata(property) == null) {
                    continue;
                }
        #>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => <#= "item." + GetValueExpression(property) #>)
                </td>
        <#
        }
    }
    .... more code ...
    </tr>
}
```

So, here it goes over the properties of our model and creates a row header for each member. 
If you see, between <# #> goes code and between <#= #> goes "write" or output. On line 88:

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => <#= "item." + GetValueExpression(property) #>)
```

So, let's say we are now writing "Speed" column. It will write

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Speed)
```

I hope it's good enough for starting. Just add a new T4 into that directory in your web app (MvcViews) and it will be available as a new template in "Add new view" dialog. You can automate most of tedious work.

T4's are difficult to debug, so make small changes every time and test. There are some t4 editor syntax helpers for Visual Studio:

[Tangible syntax highlight](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/784cf592-b797-4d4d-ad33-331fcf63faad)
[Devart editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a42a8538-8d6e-491b-8097-5a8a00174d37)

I used Tangible but now I will try Devart.

Tell me how you do.